# IntelliJ PHP custom inspection: how to have visitPhpFunctionCall being called?

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I'm making an IntelliJ plugin to add some inspections to PHP language. In the `plugin.xml`, I've declared my inspection:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <localInspection
            language="PHP"
            groupPath="PHP,Php Inspections (MTA)"
            shortName="UnsafeCallToHeaderInspection"
            displayName="Unsafe call to 'header()' function"
            groupName="Security"
            enabledByDefault="true"
            level="ERROR"
            implementationClass="com.ge.sdc.intellij.mtaplugin.security.php.UnsafeCallToHeaderInspection"/>

</extensions>

<application-components>
    <component>
        <implementation-class>com.ge.sdc.intellij.mtaplugin.MtaApplicationComponent</implementation-class>
    </component>
</application-components>
```

In my inspection class, I've extended `PhpInspection` and I'm building a PhpElementVisitor

```
package com.ge.sdc.intellij.mtaplugin.security.php;

import com.intellij.codeInspection.ProblemsHolder;
import com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElement;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElementVisitor;
import com.jetbrains.php.lang.inspections.PhpInspection;
import com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.FunctionReference;
import com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.visitors.PhpElementVisitor;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public class UnsafeCallToHeaderInspection extends PhpInspection {
    private Logger log = Logger.getInstance(UnsafeCallToHeaderInspection.class);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getStaticDescription() {
        return "Calls to 'header()' function must only use constant strings or safe-known patterns." +
                " Otherwise, this could allow arbitrary data to be passed in HTTP headers, and would then alter the behavior of the browser (or client)." +
                "Ie: Inserting a custom Content-Security-Policy or a custom Content-Type can break several securities and be a breach.";
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public PsiElementVisitor buildVisitor(@NotNull final ProblemsHolder problemsHolder, final boolean isOnTheFly) {
        return new PhpElementVisitor() {
            @Override
            public void visitPhpFunctionCall(FunctionReference reference) {
                log.debug("visitPhpFunctionCall called");
                super.visitPhpFunctionCall(reference);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitElement(PsiElement element) {
                log.debug("visitElement called");
                super.visitElement(element);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But when I debug or run the plugin, and open a PHP file like this one:

```
<?php
header($headerName);
```

I only see the "visitElement" called in the debug window, and no call to "visitPhpFunctionCall".

How do I make IntelliJ do the call to the right visitor method so I can manipulate a `FunctionReference` in that visitor method instead of an abstracted `PsiElement`?

---

What I've tried so far:

I've looked at the `php.jar` library, and took `PhpSillyAssignmentInspection` as an example, but I see no difference with my code here. I've also tryed to mimic https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/ and still found no way to have `visitPhpFunctionCall` being called. Last, I've tried to load that https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/ plugin and run it, but I saw no inspection either...

Despite, the plugin seems properly loaded and the inspection seems to be recognized too, because when I head up in the "Settings / Inspections", I see the newly added inspection under the "PHP" ones. But it seems that I cannot make IntelliJ call the `visitPhpFunctionCall` instead of `visitElement` (which is far too generic IMO to be actually usable).

Answer (score 0):

After following again the hints at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206752935-com-jetbrains-php-classes-availability, I've seen that I added the wrong `php.jar` in the wrong place.

I must use the `php.jar` from the **sandboxed** IntelliJ (`C:\Users\212636336\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\plugins-sandbox`), and not from the IntelliJ I am using to develop the plugin. And that jar must be in the classpath of this sandboxed IntelliJ SDK, and not added as an "external library" like I did.